# Does Go support volatile / non-volatile variables?

Tags: go

I'm new to the language so bear with me.

I am curious how GO handles data storage available to threads, in the sense that non-local variables can also be non-volatile, like in Java for instance.

GO has the concept of channel, which, by it's nature -- inter thread communication, means it bypasses processor cache, and reads/writes to heap directly.

Also, have not found any reference to volatile in the go lang documentation.

Comment: There is an assumption here that `volatile` has the Java/.NET meaning instead of the C/C++ meaning.

Answer (score 18):

**TL;DR**: Go does not have a keyword to make a variable safe for multiple goroutines to write/read it. Use the `sync/atomic` package for that. Or better yet [Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating](http://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating).

---

Two answers for the [two meanings of `volatile`](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484)
[image: volatile Ven diagram]

## .NET/Java *concurrency*

Some excerpts from the [Go Memory Model](http://golang.org/ref/mem).

> If the effects of a goroutine must be observed by another goroutine,
> use a synchronization mechanism such as a lock or channel
> communication to establish a relative ordering.

One of the examples from the [Incorrect Synchronization](http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_9) section is an example of busy waiting on value.

> Worse, there is no guarantee that the write to done will ever be
> observed by main, since there are no synchronization events between
> the two threads. The loop in main is not guaranteed to finish.

Indeed, this code([play.golang.org/p/K8ndH7DUzq](http://play.golang.org/p/K8ndH7DUzq)) never exits.

## C/C++ *non-standard memory*

Go's memory model does not provide a way to address non-standard memory. If you have raw access to a device's I/O bus you'll need to use assembly or C to safely write values to the memory locations. I have only ever needed to do this in a device driver which generally precludes use of Go.

Comment: The referenced code is not exiting because the main loop is blocking the go routine from executing. By increasing the runtime.GOMAXPROCS to 2 the code is exiting: https://play.golang.org/p/n-sC8jISyw

Comment: @PSanetra Good point to mention the number of cores. Anyways, the main loop is not blocking the goroutine. It depends on how Go is implemented, i.e. how Go compiler is designed, but theoretically the goroutine can be executed(or not), even if there is only 1 CPU.

Comment: as for now mentioned playground code exits without setting gomaxprocs

Answer (score 5):

The [Go Memory Model](http://golang.org/ref/mem) documentation explains why the concept of 'volatile' has no application in Go.

Loosely: Among other things, goroutines are free to keep goroutine-local changes cached in registers so those changes are not observable by other goroutines. To "flush" those changes to memory, a synchronization must be performed. Either by using locks or by communicating (channel send or receive).

Comment: The Go memory model says nothing about why volatile isn't supported, nor does it explain why volatile has no application in Go. Instead, it explains how it does work. The existence of volatile is precisely meant to tag variables that otherwise would also follow different rules in C or C++.

Comment: What about variables which sit outside a function, can they be accessed from within the function? If so, if that function is run o a separate thread, is that outer variable synced to heap or not, upon update?

Comment: @GustavoNiemeyer: If you cannot derive that from that document doesn't mean it's not there. And I have actually included the hint of the derivation in the "Losely" paragraph. Volatile _memory_ variables can get synced by forced access (that's what C does). Values existing only in a register of some other goroutine cannot be handled the same way. And the memory model allows such implementation, while C will never put a volatile variable in register only if updated.

Comment: @Raul: Local variable of global, the Memory model applies in the same way. No sync means no guarantee that the change can be observed by others.

Comment: @jnml IMO you should add the content of your comments to your answer as it makes your point clear, which your answer currently does not. (Not in an easy way, that is)

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is that volatile is not supported by the current Go specification, period.

If you do have one of the use cases where volatile is necessary, such as low-level atomic memory access that is unsupported by [existing](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/) [packages](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) in the standard library, or unbuffered access to hardware mapped memory, you'll need to link in a C or assembly file.

Note that if you do use C or assembly as understood by the GC compiler suite, you don't even need cgo for that, since the [568]c C/asm compilers are also able to handle it.

You can find examples of that in Go's source code. For example:

- http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/sema.goc
- http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/atomic_arm.c

Grep for many other instances.

For how memory access in Go does work, check out [The Go Memory Model](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/).

Answer (score 4):

No, go does not support the volatile or register statement.

See [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/Uf6GDcUgEQU/1Sw4aP_i0VoJ) for more information.
This is also noted in the [Go for C++ Programmers guide](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/GoForCPPProgrammers).