# Is this because the go compiler optimized the code?

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
        }
    }()
    <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
    println(i)
}
```

The output is always `1`.

However it's absolutely that 1s is enough for the `for` loop to go over many many times.

I think the `i` in the closure is the `i` in the `main` func.

See the code below.

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
            println("+1")
        }
    }()
    <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
    println(i)
}
```

After many lines of "+1", the output is exactly a great number as expected.

Comment: The program does not print the expected value because there's a data race on variable `i`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [**The Go Memory Model**](https://golang.org/ref/mem)
>
> Version of May 31, 2014
>
> **Introduction**
>
> The Go memory model specifies the conditions under which reads of a
>   variable in one goroutine can be guaranteed to observe values produced
>   by writes to the same variable in a different goroutine.
>
> **Advice**
>
> Programs that modify data being simultaneously accessed by multiple
>   goroutines must serialize such access.
>
> To serialize access, protect the data with channel operations or other
>   synchronization primitives such as those in the sync and sync/atomic
>   packages.
>
> If you must read the rest of this document to understand the behavior
>   of your program, you are being too clever.
>
> Don't be clever.
>
> **Synchronization**
>
> ```
> var a string
>
> func hello() {
>   go func() { a = "hello" }()
>   print(a)
> }
> ```
>
> the assignment to a is not followed by any synchronization event, so
>   it is not guaranteed to be observed by any other goroutine. In fact,
>   an aggressive compiler might delete the entire go statement.

---

The assignment to `i`, via increment `i++` (`i = i + 1`), is not followed by any synchronization event, so it is not guaranteed to be observed by any other goroutine. In fact, an aggressive compiler might delete the entire `i++` statement.

For example,

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
        }
    }()
    <-time.After(1 * time.Millisecond)
    println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

The goroutine reduces to:

```
"".main.func1 STEXT nosplit size=2 args=0x8 locals=0x0
    0x0000 00000 (elide.go:7)   TEXT    "".main.func1(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-8
    0x0000 00000 (elide.go:7)   FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·2a5305abe05176240e61b8620e19a815(SB)
    0x0000 00000 (elide.go:7)   FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x0000 00000 (elide.go:9)   JMP 0
```

To the compiler,

```
for {
    i++
}
```

can be implemented by incrementing a register forever, essentially a no-op `for` loop.

```
for { }
```

After inserting a `print` statement,

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
            println("+1")
        }
    }()
    <-time.After(1 * time.Millisecond)
    println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
+1
+1
<< SNIP >>
+1
+1
432
```

The goroutine expands to,

```
"".main.func1 STEXT size=81 args=0x8 locals=0x18
    0x0000 00000 (elide.go:7)   TEXT    "".main.func1(SB), $24-8
    0x0000 00000 (elide.go:7)   MOVQ    (TLS), CX
    0x0009 00009 (elide.go:7)   CMPQ    SP, 16(CX)
    0x000d 00013 (elide.go:7)   JLS 74
    0x000f 00015 (elide.go:7)   SUBQ    $24, SP
    0x0013 00019 (elide.go:7)   MOVQ    BP, 16(SP)
    0x0018 00024 (elide.go:7)   LEAQ    16(SP), BP
    0x001d 00029 (elide.go:7)   FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·a36216b97439c93dafebe03e7f0808b5(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (elide.go:7)   FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·33cdeccccebe80329f1fdbee7f5874cb(SB)
    0x001d 00029 (elide.go:8)   MOVQ    "".&i+32(SP), AX
    0x0022 00034 (elide.go:9)   INCQ    (AX)
    0x0025 00037 (elide.go:10)  PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x0025 00037 (elide.go:10)  CALL    runtime.printlock(SB)
    0x002a 00042 (elide.go:10)  LEAQ    go.string."+1\n"(SB), AX
    0x0031 00049 (elide.go:10)  MOVQ    AX, (SP)
    0x0035 00053 (elide.go:10)  MOVQ    $3, 8(SP)
    0x003e 00062 (elide.go:10)  PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x003e 00062 (elide.go:10)  CALL    runtime.printstring(SB)
    0x0043 00067 (elide.go:10)  PCDATA  $0, $0
    0x0043 00067 (elide.go:10)  CALL    runtime.printunlock(SB)
    0x0048 00072 (elide.go:9)   JMP 29
    0x004a 00074 (elide.go:9)   NOP
    0x004a 00074 (elide.go:7)   PCDATA  $0, $-1
    0x004a 00074 (elide.go:7)   CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
    0x004f 00079 (elide.go:7)   JMP 0
```

The increased complexity of the goroutine means that the compiler no longer considers dedicating a register to the value of `i`. The in-memory value of `i` is incremented, which makes the updates visible, with a data race, to the `main` goroutine.

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE

Read at 0x00c420094000 by 
main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/lucky.go:14 +0xac

Previous write at 0x00c420094000 by 
goroutine 5:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/lucky.go:9 +0x4e

Goroutine 5 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/peter/gopath/src/lucky.go:7 +0x7a
==================
```

---

For your expected result, add some synchronization,

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    mx := new(sync.Mutex)
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            mx.Lock()
            i++
            mx.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    <-time.After(1 * time.Second)
    mx.Lock()
    println(i)
    mx.Unlock()
}
```

Output:

```
41807838
```

Answer (score 2):

Concurrent access to the variable `i` need to be synchronized:

> **synchronization** is better done with channels or the facilities of the
>   sync package. Share memory by communicating; don't communicate by
>   sharing memory.

ref: https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/

---

This is interesting, so I'm sharing my experiments:

0- Your code using `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` (**not recommended-not synchronized**):

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println(i)
}
```

output:

```
1
```

---

1- Using `i := new(int)` (**not recommended-not synchronized**):

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    i := new(int)
    go func() {
        for {
            *i++
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println(*i)
}
```

output(CPU: i7-7700K @ 4.2GHz):

```
772252413
```

---

2- Synchronizing using `atomic.AddInt64(&i, 1)`([Package atomic provides low-level atomic memory primitives useful for implementing synchronization algorithms](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/)):

```
package main

import (
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    i := int64(1)
    go func() {
        for {
            atomic.AddInt64(&i, 1) // free running counter
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println(atomic.LoadInt64(&i)) // sampling the counter
}
```

output:

```
233008800
```

---

3- Synchronizing using `chan int`:

```
package main

import "time"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        timeout := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
        defer timeout.Stop()
        i := 1
        for {
            select {
            case <-timeout.C:
                ch <- i
                return
            default:
                i++
            }
        }
    }()
    //time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println(<-ch)
}
```

output:

```
272702341
```

---

4- Synchronizing using `sync.WaitGroup`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var done sync.WaitGroup
    done.Add(1)
    i := 1
    go func() {
        defer done.Done()
        timeout := time.NewTimer(1 * time.Second)
        defer timeout.Stop()
        for {
            select {
            case <-timeout.C:
                return
            default:
                i++
            }
        }
    }()
    done.Wait()
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

output:

```
261459418
```

---

5- Synchronizing using quit channel:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    i := 1
    go func() {
        for {
            i++
            select {
            case <-quit:
                return
            default:
            }
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    quit <- struct{}{}
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

output:

```
277366276
```

---

6- Synchronizing using `sync.RWMutex`:

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var i rwm
    go func() {
        for {
            i.inc() // free running counter
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    println(i.read()) // sampling the counter
}

type rwm struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    i int
}

func (l *rwm) inc() {
    l.Lock()
    defer l.Unlock()
    l.i++
}
func (l *rwm) read() int {
    l.RLock()
    defer l.RUnlock()
    return l.i
}
```

output:

```
24271318
```

---

related topics:

[The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem)
[There is no equivalent to volatile and register in Go](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/Uf6GDcUgEQU/1Sw4aP_i0VoJ)
[Does Go support volatile / non-volatile variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491032/does-go-support-volatile-non-volatile-variables)

Comment: The primary virtue of a program is correctness. You don't say which examples are incorrect. For example, at least examples 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Dear @peterSO: I think example 2 has no problem, do you see any? (using `atomic.AddInt64(&i, 1)` )

Comment: The Go memory model contains no explicit mention of atomic variables. Some have argued for, at best, somethiing like this: An implementation should ensure that the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic operation will become visible to all other goroutines in a finite period of time. You would see updated values of `i` sometime between now and something less than infinity. Essentially, the value of `i` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, `LoadInt64 atomically loads *addr.` just samples at moment system provided, it is guaranteed  **atomic synchronization** but time of sampling is unknown.  so using example 2 here is OK, but it depends to use case. thanks again.